# Updating navigation property for multiple entities at once in .NET Core & EF Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, relationship

I have a relationship that is set up as fully defined which I am having trouble with when updating multiple navigation properties

Parent:

```
class Parent 
{
    // ...
    public List<ParentItem> items { get; set; }
}
```

Parent item:

```
class ParentItem 
{
    // ...
    public Parent parent { get; set; }
    public Guid parentId { get; set; }
}
```

Entity configuration for `Parent`:

```
builder
    .HasMany(parent => parent.items)
    .WithOne(item => item.parent)
       .HasForeignKey(item => item.parentId);
```

Entity configuration for `Child`:

```
builder
    .HasOne(i => i.box)
    .WithMany(b => b.items)
    .HasForeignKey(i => i.boxId)
    .IsRequired();
```

My function to update:

```
public IList<BoxItem> GetFromIdList(string sub, IList<Guid> ids)
{
    var query = m_context.items.Where( (i) => i.userId == sub && ids.Contains(i.id));
    return IncludeEntities(query).ToList();
}

public void AssignNewParent(string sub, IList<Guid> itemIds, Guid currentParentId, Guid newParentId)
{
    var itemsToUpdate = GetFromIdList(sub, itemIds).ToList();

    foreach (var item in itemsToUpdate)
    {
       item.parentId = newParentId;
    }

    m_context.SaveChanges();
}
```

What is happening: whenever I try to update the navigation property for more than one item, I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
>
> at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.ValueCollection.Enumerator.MoveNext()

If I try to use the same code but rather than targeting all itemIds and just apply the changes for a single entity all works well.

I am referring to the official Microsoft documentation when I try to understand what is going wrong but I can't really figure it out.

Documentation I am looking at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/relationship-changes

Further can be mentioned that if I do not call the `SaveChanges` method, no error is yielded.

Looking forward to getting a better understanding of what is going wrong here. All help appreciated.

Comment: Is the code example the exact code you are attempting to run, or have you tried to simplify it because you mention "whenever I try to update the navigation property..." yet your example is not touching any navigation property. The error implies you are trying to alter a collection within a loop which your example is not doing. You will likely need to provide the exact code exhibiting the problem where someone might spot the issue.